# Adding certificate to trusted root authority

Tags: certificate, ssl-certificate, windows-vista

I have moved to Windows Vista Business recently and am facing an issue with
installng my networks cetiicate in the trusted root authority. on clicking on
install certificate, i select the store where the certificat should be
stored, which is Trusted Root Authorities-->Local Computer In XP. but in
Vista i am not getting the Option to store on Local Computer. instead i only
get Registry and Smart Card.
Anyone who can help me to add the certificate in the Local computer Store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have just found the solition for my problem,may be someone needs it.

1. Vista-Accessories-Command prompt -right click and select "Run as
   administrator"
   2 From the command prompt type "c:\temp\testroot.cer"
2. Click on the Install Certificate button, Next
3. Select Place all certificates in the following store, Browse
4. Select Show physical stores, scroll up, expand Trusted Root
   Certification Authorities, select Local Computer, OK, Next,
   Finish