# How can adding certificate to the trusted root certificates

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to make a web application, but when I browse my index page, I got this message:

> This project is configured to use SSL. To void SSL warning in the browser you can choose to trust the self-signed certificate that IIS Express has generated.
>
> Would you like to trust the IIS Express SSL certificate?

I pressed yes, after that I got this message:

> Adding the certificate to the Trusted Root Certificates store failed with following error.
>
> The access control list(ACL) structure is invalid.

After these messages my page shown in my browser but every time these messages shown at my face.

Note:
I'm just learning by myself

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of this:  "Adding certificate to trusted root authority." Link is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912287/adding-certificate-to-trusted-root-authority)

Answer (score 0):

Import your CA certificate to your resources

```
     X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(CertInstall.Properties.Resources.CA);
            X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.AuthRoot, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            store.Add(cert); //where cert is an X509Certificate object
            store.Close();
```